# What is the easiest way to differentiate between function calls from three different jqxgrid calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, jqxgrid

I have three jqxgrids that call the same function to create a new account (which is a jq ui dialogue). What is the easiest or best way to differentiate between which grid was called.

My code:

```
$("#divNewAccountDetails").dialog({
    autoOpen: F,
    modal: T,
    title: "New Account",
    width: 600,
    close: function () {
    },
    buttons: {
        "Save & Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

            var _Object, indexes, _row1, _row2, _row3;

            _Object = $("#jqxAccountDropdownGrid");
            indexes = $(_Object).jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');
            for (var index in indexes) {
                _row1 = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', index);

                if (typeof _row1["AccountName"] !== "undefind") {
                    if (_row1["AccountName"].toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
                        alert("Account");
                        $(_Object).jqxGrid('clearselection');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            _Object = $("#jqxPurchaseAccountDropdownGrid");
            indexes = $(_Object).jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');
            for (var index in indexes) {
                _row2 = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', index);

                if (typeof _row2["AccountName"] !== "undefind") {
                    if (_row2["AccountName"].toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
                        alert("Purchase Account");
                        $(_Object).jqxGrid('clearselection');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            _Object = $("#jqxSalesAccountDropdownGrid");
            indexes = $(_Object).jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');
            for (var index in indexes) {
                _row3 = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', index);

                if (typeof _row3["AccountName"] !== "undefind") {
                    if (_row3["AccountName"].toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
                        alert("Sales Account");
                        $(_Object).jqxGrid('clearselection');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

So basically the Grids are bound to a column change and when that columns value is `"new"`, the script triggers the dialogue (code above). What is happening is that when I click the `Save & Close` button, I get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"`. What I do not understand is that I am using a logic test to check for undefined and it appears to be executing the if block anyway which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a spelling mistake of **`undefined`**. Could that be the cause? I'm not sure.

Comment: That was it. Why is it always the simplest of things :). Thank you.

Comment: Oh we all do that. Can I just propose one thing though? You seem to be doing the same thing over and over again. With all the three rows, you are doing the same thing. I suggest you to extract a function out of them. Reusability you know.

Comment: Thats the next thing I am going to do. Just needed a way to differentiate between which grid called the add new account dialogue. This was just a quick and dirty method first, then comes the beautification process. :)